# R Reading fwf files with different width spacing in dataset

Tags: r, fixed-width, read.table

I've got stuck up while reading fwf files.

My issue is that I do not have uniform spacing with each column. It seems that each row has a different width. How can I correct this?

Example here:

```
NAME MARKS  
ABC  100  
BCA       90
```

I appreciate any comments that help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: If there's different amounts of whitespace separating fields, then you don't have a fixed-width file. It looks like you have a whitespace-separated file. Did you try `read.table('file.txt',header=T)`? It should work, since the default separator is any amount of whitespace.

Comment: @bgoldst  Its working.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read.table(text=c('NAME MARKS  ','ABC  100  ','BCA       90'),header=T);
##   NAME MARKS
## 1  ABC   100
## 2  BCA    90
```